# how to use Text Command in Tkinter to insert values into my database?

Tags: sqlite, tkinter

I'm trying to use the "Text" command in Tkinter to enable the user to input their address (in my gui app) , I created a function 'insert' which inserts the values as provided by the user  ,like in "Entry" command we use "textvar" but when using the text command textvar gives an error.
This is the insert command I use to insert values into the database.

```
def insert():
e=x.get()
f=y.get()
g=z.get()
h=a.get()
i=b.get()
j=c.get()
k=d.get()
l=clicked1.get()
m=clicked2.get()
n=clicked3.get()
o=clicked4.get()
p=clicked5.get()
q=clicked6.get()
r=radio1.get()
s=radio2.get()

cr.execute("insert into university_management(Name,Gender,Religion,Caste,Address,State,Phone_Number,Guardians_Name,Registration_Number,Roll_Number,College_Name,Stream,Discipline,Honours_Specialization,Year_Semester)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(e,r,l,s,f,q,g,h,i,j,k,m,n,o,p))    

db.commit()
```

This the where I use the text command.

```
l5=Label(w,text='Address :',font='none 14').place(x=3,y=130)
e3=Text(w,font='none 12',textvar=y)
e3.place(width=185,height=100,x=230,y=125)
```

What am I supposed to do input the value entered here to my database.

Comment: The text widget is well documented, and there are countless examples of the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text widget get method works a bit differently than entry. Use following to get value - e3.get("1.0",END). No need to use textvar

Comment: normally you should use "end-1c" as the second index. "end" will return an extra newline that is automatically created by the text widget.